# Python テキストファイルの名前に日付を入れたい

Tags: python

Pythonでテキストファイルの名前に現在の日付と時間を入れたいのですが、変数を入れる方法がわからないです。

renameの方法はわかっているのですが文字列で名前を指定するのではなく、ファイル名にプログラムを実行した現在時刻を反映させたいと考えています。現在書き換えのコ‌​ードを下記に記しておきます。よろしくお願い致します。

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
os.rename("sample.txt", d.txt)
```

dの部分に日付時刻を入れたいです。

Comment: ファイルをリネームする方法はおわかりでしょうか？　リネームする新しいファイル名として、元のファイル名に日時を結合した文字列を指定すればいいだけだと思いますが。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
renameの方法はわかっているのですが文字列で名前を指定するのではなく、ファイル名にプログラムを実行した現在時刻を反映させたいと考えています。現在書き換えのコードを下記に記しておきます。よろしくお願い致します。

import os
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
datetime
os.rename("sample.txt",d.txt)

dの部分に日付時刻を入れたいです。

Comment: 情報がそのくらい具体的になると、回答が付きやすくて良いのではないかと思います。本文の方に反映させていただきましたが、ご自分でもいつでも編集できますので、ご活用ください。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
今回初めて利用させていただいたので、本文への反映などわからないことだらけでした。
わざわざありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

「python 日付 フォーマット」で検索すると、datetime型を文字列型に変更する方法が出てきます。
dの部分に日付時刻を入れるには、`os.rename("sample.txt", d.txt)`を以下のように書き換えます。

**python 2.6以降**

```
os.rename("sample.txt", "{0:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.txt".format(d))
```

**python 2.6より前から利用可**

```
os.rename("sample.txt", d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S") + ".txt")
```

下記は一連のファイル作成とリネームのサンプルコードです。
リネーム時に拡張子をそのまま保持するようにしてみました。参考まで。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import shutil
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
#現在時刻を織り込んだファイル名を生成
fmt_name = "hoge_{0:%Y%m%d-%H%M%S}.txt".format(now)
with open(fmt_name, "w") as f:
    f.write("汝、今何時？")
#テスト用に日付のないファイルを作成
plain_name = "fuga.piyo.txt" 
shutil.copy(fmt_name, plain_name)
#現在時刻を拡張子の直前に追加
ss = plain_name.split(".", 1)
new_name = "{0}_{1:%Y%m%d-%H%M%S}.{2}".format(ss[0], now, ss[1])
#既存のファイルをリネーム
os.rename(plain_name, new_name)
```

Comment: datetimeオブジェクトを直接フォーマットできるんですねぇ！知らなかった。

Comment: なぜこれが動くのか不思議だったのですが、`__format__`メソッドが定義されているオブジェクトなら、なんでもフォーマット可能ということがわかりました。

Comment: いわゆる「特殊メソッド」というものですね。特に何も考えずに使っていましたが、`__add__`で`+`演算子の挙動を定義するように、`__format__`メソッドを記述することで独自クラスでも`str.format() `の挙動を制御できる仕組みがdatetimeに実装されているため、フォーマットできるということを改めて知りました。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: お二人のやり取りで実際のコードの意味についても深く知ることができました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: ちなみに、`d.strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S.txt")`でもできます。`... + ".txt"`は、不要です。